# Error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, compiler-errors

```
import PyPDF4
from google.colab import files
files.upload()
fileReader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader('ITC-1.pdf')
s=""
for i in range(2, fileReader.numPages):
    s+=fileReader.getPage(i).extractText()


sentences = []
while s.find('.') != -1:
    index = s.find('.')
    sentences.append(s[:index])
    s = s[index+1:]

text_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset('ITC-1.pdf').filter(lambda x: tf.cast(tf.strings.length(x), bool))
vectorize_layer.adapt(text_ds.batch(1024))
inverse_vocab = vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary()
```

The last line in the code above shows the error. I saw several posts to understand what it means, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I cannot use my local machine because I would be needing access to GPUs. Please suggest a workaround for this. Thanks!

PS: Following the code here https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/text/word2vec.ipynb#scrollTo=haJUNjSB60Kh, the difference is in the way I am reading the file. If there are better ways to do it, pleasee let me know!

Comment: you're reading pdf to 's' and never using It? then you're using TextLineDataset() which takes a text file as input to read a pdf?

Comment: @harry yes I understand I'm taking the input incorrectly. Could you please suggest a better way? I have edited the question to include the link from where the original code is

Comment: Do you really want to read text from pdf or any text file will suffice?

Comment: i want to read text from pdf...maybe can do some manual conversion if that helps? (but the data is huge and there might be formatting issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pdfplumber
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
import tensorflow as tf

f = open('test.txt', 'w')

with pdfplumber.open(r'test.pdf') as pdf:
    for page in pdf.pages:
      f.write(page.extract_text())
f.close()
layer = preprocessing.TextVectorization()
text_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset('test.txt').filter(lambda x: tf.cast(tf.strings.length(x), bool))

layer.adapt(text_ds.batch(1024))
inverse_vocab = layer.get_vocabulary()
```

You could do something like this:

1. read pdf using pdfplumber.
2. Write the pages to a text file.
3. Then create dataset using that text file.

Comment: Did this and got the error: PDFSyntaxError: No /Root object! - Is this really a PDF?

Comment: Could be a problem with your pdf, try with a different one.